# Eclipse CDT white bar removal

Tags: eclipse, ide, themes, editor, settings

I have spent the last few days getting my eclipse java installation to play well with eclipse CDT after doing that i wanted to use the built in eclipse dark theme but when i have it applied there is a white bar that really bugs me, is there a way to remove this?

[image]

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: @howlger i use eclipse oxygen

Comment: Which version exactly? Oxygen.3? Windows, Linux or macOS?

Comment: @howlger i am using oxygen.3 on windows